# How to group by two columns at the same time?

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to group by two columns at the same time and return the average of their values. For example, this chart:

| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | P2 | 10 |
| P1 | P3 | 15 |
| P2 | P1 | 20 |
| P3 | P2 | 30 |

should return:
P1 : 15 (10 + 15 + 20 / 3)
P2: 20
P3: 22.5

I've tried using union and group by one of the columns but it returns a separate value for each P based on its col A and col B average.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.col1, AVG(t.col2)
FROM
(
SELECT Col_A AS [col1], Col_C AS [col2] FROM YourTable
UNION
SELECT Col_B AS [col1], Col_C AS [col2] FROM YourTable
) as t
GROUP BY t.col1
```

And here is another way:

```
DECLARE @Tabletemp TABLE
(
    col1 VARCHAR(2),
    col2 FLOAT
)

INSERT @Tabletemp SELECT Col_A, Col_C FROM YourTable
INSERT @Tabletemp SELECT Col_B, Col_C FROM YourTable

SELECT col1, AVG(col2) FROM @Tabletemp GROUP BY col1
```

P.S. By "YourTable", I mean the original table with 3 columns.